# Section of VBA code is stuck in a loop

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

From what I can see this code should work but it ends up stuck in a loop so obviously there is still an issue.

- The intention is to start at cell E70 and paste a value obtained from cell X38.
- Move down to the next cell of column E and repeat pasting values from cell X38 until the corresponding row number of column D is empty.

The code:

```
Option Explicit    

Sub Variability_Score()    
'        
' Variability_Score Macro    
'        
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+p    
'        
    Dim rowNo As Integer
    rowNo = 70

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(rowNo, 4))  

        Range("$X$38").Select    
        Selection.Copy    
        Range("E70").Select    
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _    
            :=False, Transpose:=False    
            ActiveCell.offset(RowOffset:=1).Activate    

            rowNo = rowNo + 1    
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't make any sense. You use `rowNo`, but then explicitly `Select` and paste into E70, then you `Activate` E71 for no reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The selection text was there from the recording I used at the start. Removing these and the row offset line did the trick.